# Wordpress very high load when click "Publish"

Tags: server-load

My site is currently having 70000 posts, and generate about 1.4 million views per month.

Specs are Quad-core Xeon, 8GB RAM, FCGI

Plugins: W3 Total Cache, Jetpack, WP Page Navi, Contact Form 7, Discuz, Events

Problem: Whenever my uploaders publish news, the server load will spike. and When 2 or 3 of them upload news at the same time, the server will hang for a few minutes (Internal Server Error) and then back to normal again.

Tried: Changing permalinks, changing to wpsupercache, optimised theme queries.

I've been having this problem for a year plus but still did not find a way to solve. Anyone have any idea? Thank you.

PS: All plugins and wordpress are updated everyday.

Comment: How about proper formatting: Links to plugins, Uppercase letters when sentences start, etc., Showing debug logs, Performance meter output, Output from WP Debug plugins about queries, etc.etc... Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe reading the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/HyperDB

Comment: @brasoflo: I think your comment deserves to be answer. I would have upvoted it if it was (not for the pertness of it, but for the link - a feature I was not aware of).

Comment: @JohannesPille - I understand that _one link_ answers are not considered good ones. From my side, I wasn't aware of the word _pertness_, had to look in the diccionary :p

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, will look into it. but hyperDB seemed very, very complicated! even the codex didnt mention much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the size of your site. You have huge site and now it's not enough to have only W3 Total Cache plugin for caching.

During publishing post, WordPress performs a lot of database calls, it updates some information about posts in database. So I can suppose that the weakest spot is in querying to database.

How to solve the issue? It's very hard to give you one bulletproof solution, which will 100% help you. One suggestion could be in recommendation to try HyperDB as mentioned @brasofilo, but it requires complete understanding in advanced database optimization. Another suggestion could be in hiring a freelancer, who can help you to optimize your site and make it working better.

Comment: holy... didnt know wordpress got this kind of limits! so the huge sites like mashable etc they use hyperDB to host so much posts? oh man... hyperDB sounded quite hard from the codex... thanks for the reply

Comment: @Nders I don't know how mashable is build, but I think it is not just single WP instance from the box. I suppose that they use more then one backend servers, maybe something like Amazon EC2.

Comment: so does this mean that one server is not enough to host that many posts i have? if it is the case I can request for more resources from my company. but i need someone with exprience in this to confirm, thanks.

Comment: @Nders it's very complex question, I can't confirm and guaranty anything, because I know almost nothing about your site and your system. Try to find freelancer, who will be able to make audit of your site and create optimization plan. Once you have such plan you will be aware what you need.